# regex for '(number)'

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all the `'`s around numbers, to nothing.. for example:

```
'1' to 1 

'100' to 100
```

which is the optimal way to do this? is there a regex to do this so I can use it in the `replace()` function of the `String` class?

Comment: Can you clarify that all these numbers are integers? Are there any doubles like '10.5' or '10.3333'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` method with regex support:

```
str = str.replaceAll("'(\\d+)'", "$1");
```

`(\\d+)` will match and group digits surrounded by single quotes on either side and then we use `$1` in replacement which is the back-reference to captured value in regex.

Answer (score -1):

If it's in a String and you want the integer why don't you just parse it.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("100");
```